# We need to stream file in web browser by using react js and node

Tags: node.js, excel, reactjs

We need to stream excel file on web browser with all excel functionalities (methods) by using node and react js. Is it possible to stream excel file in web browser with their all functions ?

Comment: You want to recreate Excel in the browser? I don't know if microsoft offers their client-side Excel used in OneDrive as a framework or component.
You can perhaps embed the edit view of an Excel file in OnDrive in your site.

Comment: can you please share any link to embeb excel file in site

Comment: It depends on your oneDrive account and excel file. if you work on windows: go to your one drive folder, upload an excel file and embed the link to the edit view in an IFrame. I haven't test that, maybe there ist trouble with authentication, but it's worth a try